# Windows 7, PowerPoint 2003

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, bullets

I'm including a custom-made bullet point in a PowerPoint 2003 presentation.

Will a user on another machine be able to see it and use it?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested this with a coworker. Yes, it works. Apparently PowerPoint embeds custom bullet points by default.

Comment: If they're graphics, yes.  If you define a custom bullet using a font, it may or may not work if the other user doesn't have the necessary font installed.